# Howto integrate spring-social authentication with spring-security?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-social

I've got a little webapp secured by spring-security using a username/password combo on a sql-db as credentials.

I now want to add facebook/twitter authentication with spring-social. Using the examples I am  able to store the users credentials in my db. I'm now working on authenticating the user against his current session on my app using the following piece of code:

```
public String signIn(String userId, Connection<?> connection, NativeWebRequest request) {

    User user = userService.getUserById(Long.parseLong(userId));
    user.setPassword(this.passwordEncoder.encodePassword(user.getAccessToken(), this.salt));
    this.userService.store(user);

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getDisplayName(), user.getAccessToken());

    HttpServletRequest req = request.getNativeRequest(HttpServletRequest.class); // generate session if one doesn't exist
    token.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetails(req));
    Authentication authenticatedUser = this.authenticationManager.authenticate(token);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticatedUser);

    return "/user/dashboard";
}
```

The authentication works, I am not getting any BadCredential-exceptions. But after being redirected to /user/dashboard I am thrown back to the login.

I am out of ideas, a similar piece of code for authenticating the session is working after a classical signup.

Does anyone have any ideas why this happens or how to debug this?

Thanks very much in advance!
Hendrik

Comment: It all depends. I ran into this same situation and it turned out to be that my mapping only allowed role "ROLE_ANONYMOUS", which I was denied access too after logging in. I had to change it to also allow "ROLE_USER". For some reason, this was not an issue when using spring security directly to login (eg, basic or form login).

Answer (score 1):

I have similar code that works for me, and also adds "remember me" support:

```
// lookup by id, which in my case is the login
User user = userService.findByLogin(userId);
// code to populate the user's roles
List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = ...;
// create new instance of my UserDetails implementation
UserDetailsImpl springSecurityUser = new UserDetailsImpl(user, authorities);
// create new Authentication using UserDetails instance, password, and roles
Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(springSecurityUser, user.getPassword(), authorities);
// set the Authentication in the SecurityContext
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
// optional: remember-me support (must @Autowire in TokenBasedRememberMeServices)
tokenBasedRememberMeServices.onLoginSuccess(
    (HttpServletRequest) request.getNativeRequest(),
    (HttpServletResponse) request.getNativeResponse(),
    authentication);
```